# Sitemap files on different domains

Tags: seo, sitemap

I am creating multiple sitemap files for my website. The issue is that my sitemap files are located on a different file server from my website. 
For example, I have a website by domain, `www.example.com`, however my sitemap index file and the other sitemap files reside on `www.filestack.com`.

My sitemap index file will look like:

```xml
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.84">
<sitemap>
<loc>
https://www.filestack.com/sitemap1.xml
</loc>
</sitemap>
```

Though my `sitemap1.xml` will be:

```xml
<url>
<loc>
https://www.example.com/test
</loc>
<lastmod>2017-09-04</lastmod>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
</url>
```

Is it possible to add links to do such a thing and how?

Answer (score 13):

See  [Sitemaps & Cross Submits](https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#sitemaps_cross_submits).

You have to provide a robots.txt at `https://www.example.com/robots.txt` which
links to the external sitemap:

```
Sitemap: https://www.filestack.com/sitemap1.xml
```

(This sitemap may only contain URLs from `https://www.example.com/`.)

Answer (score -2):

You can use either XML sitemap or HTML sitemap as per [Matt Cutts](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hi5DGOu1uA0) says. It's not mandatory that you must use both sitemaps. Though you can't submit an HTML sitemap to search engines, spiders can crawl your HTML sitemap and crawl pages deeper into your site. But you can not use XML sitemap that is on the different server.